# Can an iterator only be iterated once in Python?

Tags: python, iterator

It seems like an iterator object can be iterated only once in Python. For example,

```
def iterator_example():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

lst = iterator_example()

Nelemnts_first = len(list(lst))
Nelements_second = len(list(lst))

print(Nelemnts_first == Nelements_second)
```

This snippet prints **False**. But I think it should return True since the iterator length is the same. *What is happening behind the scenes?* *How do you re-use lst multiple times without consuming it?*

Comment: This is not just any iterator, it is a ***generator***.

Comment: I suggest reading the official tutorial, is sections 9.8, 9.9 and 9.10 : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators

Comment: What you're creating there is not an iterator, it's a generator. The difference is that each instance of it will only iterate through each element once, you need to create another instance of it to get the same result

Comment: Yes, indeed! Thank you for the explanation and links.

Comment: @Stef sure, but it behaves like a normal, typical iterator. IOW, you'd expect this with *any* iterator, e.g. `map`

Comment: @Stef What does it matter that it's a generator?

Comment: @nonenone it 100% is an iterator, generators *are iterators*, the whole *point* of generators is to provide you with a convenient way of defining iterators

Comment: @nonenone: All generators are iterators; you can't iterate an iterator multiple times either. Itera*ble*s are different, and non-itera*tor* iterables can be iterated repeatedly, but neither itera*tor*s nor generators can be iterated repeatedly.

Comment: "How do you re-use lst multiple times without consuming it?" You can't. Iterators should be single-pass. The reasonable thing to do here is to keep a reference to the list around and re-use the list. e.g. `lst = list(iterator_example())`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: For certain special-cases you can use `itertools.tee`, but yeah, most of the time, you'd want to convert to `list` (as you show) or just run the generator twice (when memory constraints prevent `list`ifying). `itertools.tee` is for a *very* specific use case where *all* the `tee`d iterators will be consumed roughly at the same time; if you completely consume one `tee`d iterator before beginning on the others, you use memory proportionate to just `list`ifying in the first place, and run slower than if you'd used the plain `list`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for your suggestion! I will consider it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right, i'll be more accurate if i have to explain it to someone again

Comment: @KellyBundy That makes it easier to search for documentation about it!